# Haec verba tandem mercātōrem perturbātum aliquid cōnsōlāri videntur

Tags: syntax, grammar-identification, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

In page 236 line 12–126 of lingua latina per se illustrata there is the following sentence

> Haec verba tandem mercātōrem perturbātum aliquid
> cōnsōlāri videntur.

I gets to me that it is trying to say something like *These words finally [something] is seen*. The verb *videntur* is for what I understand taking *Haec verba* as subject, *mercātōrem perturbātum* or *aliquid* as object,  for what I understand there is not indirect object in the verb *videntur*, I am also noting that there is no ablative element in the sentence, which would be the true subject of the passive form *videntur*, the best that I can do is supposing that *mercātōrem perturbātum [...] cōnsōlāri* means mercator paerturbed benig consoled or something like that, but the phrase does not make overall sense for what I know.

Comment: Aliquid here is an adverb. “Somewhat” in modern English (in rather older English “something” was used in the same sense). Interestingly “algo” in Spanish also has an adverbial meaning as well as a “something” one.

Comment: @MartinKochanski I prefer the suggestions in Spanish given that I am a native Spanish Speaker

Answer (score 3):

#### ACI and NCI

Consider this sentence:

> *Haec verba mercatorem consolari video.*
> I see that these words comfort the salesman.

It's an *accusativus cum infinitivo*.
When turned passive, it becomes a *nominativus cum infinitivo*:

> *Haec verba mercatorem consolari videntur.*
> These words seem to comfort the salesman.

For more details on these two constructions, see [this section in Allen & Greenough](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/accusative-and-infinitive) and the subsequent ones for examples and details.
I urge you to get a grip of *accusativus cum infinitivo* first, as it is a very common construction and the one used here is a passive variation of it.

Due to the neuter gender you can't tell that the subject *haec verba* turned from accusative to nominative, but it did.

#### Notes on the verbs

The verb *consolari* is a deponent one, so it looks passive but means active with an accusatives object and all.

Whether the passive of *videre* should be translated as "seem" or something else depends on context.
There is [a separate question on that](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/14685/79) if you crave details.

#### Putting it all together

Now that we have the core structure in place, we can get to decorating it with details.
The simpler additions are *tandem*, "finally", and the attribute *perturbatum*, "troubled" or "confused".
The more complicated detail is *aliquid*, which here means "to some extent".
This meaning of accusatives of neuter pronouns appears from time to time.

Thus the whole sentence might be translated as:

> *Haec verba tandem mercatorem perturbatum aliquid consolari videntur.*
> These words finally seemed to comfort the salesman a little bit.

The exact wording will depend on context given by surrounding sentences and other clues.
I don't have the book, so I can only treat the sentence in isolation.